# External JS lib included by includeScript function is not accessible

Tags: sapui5

I try to test the includeScript function to load external js library after UI5 page is loaded. It works in all of the case meaning after the script is loaded, it is accessible. However, in case having ChartContainer control, the loaded JS library is not accessible.

- Working case, pick sample page of Map Container control: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.vk.MapContainer/sample/sap.ui.vk.sample.MapContainerBasic, after the page is loaded, open Developer tools, run the script below in console panel.

```
var includeScript = sap.ui.require("sap/ui/dom/includeScript");
try {
  dateFns.isToday(new Date());
} catch (err) {
  new Promise(function(fnResolve, fnReject) {
    includeScript(
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js", 
          "datefns_js", fnResolve, fnReject);
 }).then(function() {
     console.log("datefns_js is loaded!!!")
     console.log(dateFns.isToday(new Date()));
 });
}
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

Once the dateFns is loaded, execute the next command:

```
dateFns.isToday(new Date());
```

it returns true in the console since dateFns js is loaded and accessible.

- None working case, specifically when testing ChartContainer control, open sample page of chart container control in a new session: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.ChartContainer/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ChartContainerSimpleToolbar
  Open developer tool and repeat the same steps as above. The error occurs as "Uncaught ReferenceError: dateFns is not defined" since the library is load but not accessible.

I expect the loaded external js library should be accessible with any controls having in my UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SAPUI5 documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.define):

> Modules that use Unified Module Definition (UMD) syntax, can be loaded, but only when no AMD loader is present or when they expose their export also to the global namespace, even when an AMD loader is present

Unfortunately, SAPUI5 charts use another AMD loader (`RequireJS`) and therefore your module `date-fns` will be loaded using RequireJS and not be available to the global `window` object.

To fix this, you can force the module to be always loaded over RequireJS and then to be available through the `require` method:

```html
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>

<script>
var declareLibs = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/thirdparty/require"], function () {
        requirejs.config({
            paths: {
                "date_fns": ["//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min"]
            }
        });

        resolve();
    });
});

declareLibs.then(require(["date_fns"], function (dateFns) {
    console.log("datefns_js is loaded!")
    console.log(dateFns.isToday(new Date()));
}));
</script>
```